# How can I write a multiple condition in Javascript in order to change a <div> class?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a `<div>` that takes a class depending on an if statement(`message.isSent()` returning true) like this:

```
 <div [class] = "message.isSent() ? 'my-message' : 'other-message'" class = "messageContainer" >
```

How can I give this `<div>` another class (let's say `'info-message'`) in case of another method returning true?(`message.isInfoMessage()`)

Thanks a lot

Comment: write a conditional statement outside of your html, where you build your variable which contains the class names.. then put that into your html class attribute :)

Comment: Are you using Angular?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Angular

Comment: why don't you return the result in the function?

Comment: if u use angular, look ng template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this solves the issue:

```
  <div [class] = "message.isSent() ? 'my-message' : message.isInfoMessage() ? 'info-message' : 'other-message'" class = "messageContainer" >
```

Another approach is to add a helper method to the `Message`:

Define a messageType() method:

```
type() {
   if (this.isSent()) return "my-message";
   if (this.isInfoMessage()) return "info-message";
   return "other-message";
}
```

html:

```
  <div [class] = "message.type()" class = "messageContainer" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
<div [ngClass]="( message.isSent() ) ? 'my-message' : 'other-message'" class = "messageContainer">
```

Comment: Might want to show how to include the existing `messageContainer` class, and also how to include another class that depends on a Boolean-returning function (as is asked for in the OP).